# Changing dynamic site script to work with the latest jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I got the script from : http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/
and edited it to my needs. It works well with "jquery-1.4.4". But the active class assignment for the menu buttons dont work with "jquery-1.5 and later versions".

This is the script:

```
$(function() {
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $el;        

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){    
    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);                                                        
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(600, function() {                     
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {   
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(600, function() {

                    });                     
                    $("nav a").removeClass("active");
                    $(" a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("active");
                });
            });
    };     
});
$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Than I have this simple ajax loading-spinner code which also doesnt work with the latest jquery:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
$('#spinner').fadeIn("fast");
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $('#spinner').delay(600).fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

i am not sure but try if this works for you.

```
$(" a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("active");
       //  ^-----------^-----------you have missed the " ' " single quotes
```

Comment: Wow, it works, mysteriously also the spinner :) 
Thank you man! You saved my day! Too bad I have not enough reputation right now to vote your Answer. :(

Comment: Thanks now I have seen it :)